# Second Dropdown Sub-Menu Will Not Show When Hovered Over

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navigation menu using bootstrap, and the menu worked fine when I had the second sub-menu off to the side of the first sub-menu. I've changed it to put the third level sub-menu under the dropdown's link. Now when hovered over it the third level menu will not display.

I have tried different combinations of classes and adding ids but can't seem to get it to show up on hover. I'm not using JavaScript for this currently as it worked fine with html and css.

This is a small mockup of what is going on.

```css
html {
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-top: 7px solid black;
    font-size: 62%;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}

* {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.container {
    padding-right: 0;
}

main {
 padding-bottom: 22em;
}

p {
 font-size: 
}

.extra-bold {
 font-weight: 800;
}

.semi-bold {
 font-weight: 600;
}

.bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(235,235,235,0), rgba(235,235,235,1));
    height: 129px;
}

.navbar-brand {
 margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: .5em;
}

.nav {
    min-width: 100%; 
    flex-direction: row;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-left: 10em;
}

.navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
}

.nav li {
    margin: 0em 1em;
}

.nav-link {
    color: black;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
 color: white;
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
 color: white;
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

.nav-item {
 font-size: 1.6em;
}

.nav > li.disabled > a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

.nav-link:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

.dropdown-hover {
 color: white;
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
 background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
    color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu.disabled:hover {
 color: white;
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

a.dropdown-item.dropdown.disabled:hover {
 color: white;
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
 background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
    color: white;
}

.dropdown ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
    color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#toggle:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.fa-caret-right {
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.fa-caret-right {
 line-height: 1.75;
    margin-left: .5em
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown:hover div.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

* {
    position: relative;
}

#navbarDropdown {
 color: black;
}

.dropdown-item.disabled, .dropdown-item:disabled {
 color: black;
}

.dropdown-item.disabled:hover, .dropdown-item:disabled:hover {
 color: white;
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
}

.nav-link.disabled:hover {
 color: white;
    background-color: rgb(217,0,0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://hmi.blueseaonline.net/index.php" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.1/css/light.css" integrity="sha384-Rg8mXhpzJH99uBsgdsCp9zXjkcsw/pm+s4Kgu/56eRQSd8SAszYc6hssH5MLusHl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.1/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-O68Og25nY+MZZRUiP6gm7XPDuHsNC5DgKWEoxn6+3CFcGLRXuFihbGO/8c5Ned0i" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hmi.blueseaonline.net/index.php/site/style">

</head>
<body>
  <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-right">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="min-width: 100%;">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center" style="list-style-type: none;">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="/hmi-lumber-sales/" class="nav-link disabled"id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Test <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu toggle-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <ul style="padding:0; list-style-type: none;">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown disabled" id="toggle" href="">Test <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                    
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                    
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                    
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>   
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Test</a>
                
              </li>   
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown"  href="">Test <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>   
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="">Test</a>
              </li>   
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="">Test</a>
              </li>   
            </ul>
          </div> 
        </li>   
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Test</a>
         </li>
         
        
          
                
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="" class="nav-link disabled"id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Test <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Dropdown Menu Toggle</span></a>
            
            <div class="dropdown-menu toggle-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <ul style="padding:0; list-style-type: none;">
              
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href=""Test</a>
                
              </li>   
              
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown"  href="">Test <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                    
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                    
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Test</a></li>
                    
                  </ul>
                
              </li>   
              
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="">Test</a>
                
              </li>   
              
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="">Test</a>
                
              </li>   
              
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="">Test</a>
                
              </li>   
              
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="">Test</a>
                
              </li>   
              
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="">Test</a>
                
              </li>   
              
              </ul>
            </div>
            
         </li>
         
        
          
                
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Test</a>
            
            
         </li>
         
            </ul>
          </div>
         
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>

  <!-- Load jQuery, then Popper, then Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Load Map Resizer -->
  
  <!-- Load lightbox -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I'm trying to get: [Dropdown Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdMYQ.png)